# Use of queryset inside the primarykeyrelated field in django serializers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, primary-key, django-serializer

I am quite confused why we have to write `queryset = Example.objects.all()` inside the modelserializer class when I creating an object using a foreign key in the post http call.

For eg:

```
class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    abc = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Abc.objects.all())
    
    class Meta:
        model = Class
        fields = ['id','abc'] 
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...........//

class Example(models.Model):
     abc = models.Foreignkey(Abc)
```

If it was a get call I can use `read_only= True` inside the abc pk field, but since it is to be written I am passing a single id from the frontend, but why I need to populate all objects inside the serializer field.

The docs says something like this `: The queryset used for model instance lookups when validating the field input` but cant gather what it is saying.

Comment: As the docs says, it's used for validating input data. You could filter the `queryset` and not let user create objects violating that condition. For instance, if `queryset=Abc.objects.filter(field__startswith='a')`, then the user cannot create an `Example` object and connect it to an `Abc` instance which it's `field` starts with any character except `a`.

Comment: wow, thank you so much...you expalined very precisely